# Power sockets in Ecuador - grounded or ungrounded?

Tags: power, ecuador

I am aware that Ecuador uses sockets compatible with the US/North American standard ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#North_American_and_IEC_60906-2)), but which type is more widespread: the ungrounded (type A, 2 pins) or the grounded one (type B, 3 pins)?

I'm asking because I usually use only one adapter and a multiple socket extension, which is very useful for older hotels with few power sockets, but requires a grounded socket.

Clarification: I'm not worried about the outlet not being grounded, as the devices I am usually connecting don't need that anyway, but the only multiple extensions available here (in Germany) have grounded plugs (which are also certified for higher currents), which can only be used with grounded adapters.

Comment: The answer will depend greatly on where you're trying to plug in, as older buildings are more likely to have type A sockets, while newer ones have type B.

Answer (score 4):

Based on my experience of Ecuadorian electrics, I would assume that even grounded sockets might not be grounded. On that basis, you might as well take an ungrounded adaptor. If you're going off the beaten track, it may also be worth taking a couple of light switches, a small screwdriver, and some rubber gloves.

Since you want to travel light, your best option might be to buy a plug from the US over the Internet and rewire a splitter.